# Why the sqlite cursor in android returns different values?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-cursor

I have simple query, where you can see a row:

```
SELECT substr(..., 10, 6) as X
```

If I use `cursor.getInt(...)` I get 1048 (the "wrong" value)

If I use `cursor.getString(...)` I get `"002030"` (which is correct).

So, what makes sqlite parse "002030" as 1048?

Do I have to get it as string and parse it myself every time?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `substr()` returns a string, so you should retrieve the value with `cursor.getString()`, which returns the correct result.

If you want the result as an integer, you must convert it in your sql code, either explicitly:

```
SELECT cast(substr(..., 10, 6) as integer) as X
```

or implicitly:

```
SELECT substr(..., 10, 6) + 0 as X
```

The result will be the integer `2030` without the leading `0`s.

As for the strange `1048` that you get, Java considers numeric literals starting with `0` as [octal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal) numbers, so:

```
int x = 002030;
```

assigns `1048` to `x` which is the decimal representation of the octal number `2030`.

Comment: Thank you. I still do not get it thou... why getDouble will work on substr(), and getLong/Int will not. If anything, I expected to be the other way around.

Comment: This issue needs testing. I will try to reproduce. In any case, do the conversion in sql to be on the safe side.